# How do I change the direction of a gradient in tailwind css?

Tags: gradient, tailwind-css, direction

```
 <div class="bg-gradient-to-r from-cyan-500 to-blue-500 ">
```

.
.
.
.

I have tried the above code. But it's a linear gradient, I want a vertical gradient.

Comment: Try using bg-gradient-to-t or bg-gradient-to-b

Answer (score 40, accepted):

> But it's a linear gradient, I want a vertical gradient.

`linear` is a **type** of gradient, `vertical` is a **direction**. You probably mean that you have a `horizontal` gradient but instead you want a `vertical` one. Both will be `linear` though (for example `radial` gradient does not exist in Tailwind right now, only `linear` exists).

All default available directions that you can use for `linear` gradient:

- `bg-gradient-to-t`
- `bg-gradient-to-tr`
- `bg-gradient-to-r`
- `bg-gradient-to-br`
- `bg-gradient-to-b`
- `bg-gradient-to-bl`
- `bg-gradient-to-l`
- `bg-gradient-to-tl`

So for vertical direction just use `bg-gradient-to-t` (from bottom to top) or `bg-gradient-to-b` (from top to bottom)

[More info in the docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/background-image)