# How to apply tailwind gradient diagonally?

Tags: tailwind-css

What if I want to use gradient diagonally as shown in the image? Is there any way to select an angle while applying a gradient?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I change the direction of a gradient in tailwind css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70773146/how-do-i-change-the-direction-of-a-gradient-in-tailwind-css)

Comment: You can adjust angle like mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71120394/is-there-a-way-to-adjust-the-angle-of-the-linear-gradient-in-tailwind-css/71129446#71129446)

Answer (score 2):

YOu can use the gradient lass of tailwind css like this.

Below is the example

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<div class="h-96 w-96 bg-gradient-to-tl from-slate-200 via-rose-100 to-purple-300"></div>
```